# ADODB - Switch from Mysql to Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, migration, adodb

In the light of MySQL to soon be deprecated, I need to move a large website using ADODB from MySQL to MySQLi.

Now I have looked up a few topics on Stackoverflow and thanks to the community I already have a genral idea of what needs to be done. Best topics on the matter are those ones:

[ADODB mySQLi Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839182/adodb-mysqli-connection)

[Switch large website from MySQL to MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721235/switch-large-website-from-mysql-to-mysqli)

However, I do still need a bit more clarification on my particular case, where ADODB is being used.

This is what I use to connect to the DB:

```
define('DBHOST', 'db_host');
define('DBUSER', 'db_user'); 
define('DBPASS', 'db_pass');    
define('DBNAME', 'db_name'); 

include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
$db = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$db->Connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die("Database not found!");
```

So first I am changing:

```
$db = ADONewConnection('mysql');
```

to

```
$db = ADONewConnection('mysqli');
```

That's the easy part, I guess.

Now since I am using ADODB, do I also need to change all instances of MySQL_* functions to MySQLi_* or ADODB takes care of this automatically? I think I know the answer but anyhow have to ask.

My most common MySQL_ functions are:

```
mysql_insert_id()
mysql_query()
mysql_fetch_array()
mysql_num_rows()
mysql_escape_string()
mysql_connect()
mysql_select_db()
mysql_error()
```

Most common usage is like `$variable = mysql_insert_id();` or `$v1 = mysql_query($v);`

Is there anything else I should take into consideration when moving from MySQL to MySQLi for ADODB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"do I also need to change all instances of MySQL_* functions to MySQLi_* ?"*

The answer is yes. Different MySQL APIs/functions do not intermix. You must use the same API/functions from connection to querying.

You can use the following functions, simply replacing `mysql_` by `mysqli_`, while passing a database connection in functions that require it and as the first parameter.

- I.e. `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`.

They are marked with asterisks `*`.

```
mysqli_insert_id() - *
mysqli_query() - *
mysqli_fetch_array()
mysqli_num_rows()
mysqli_escape_string() - *
mysqli_connect() - *
mysqli_select_db() - *
mysqli_error() - *
```

- Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: *...while passing db connection to functions that require it.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will do as you suggest.

Comment: Isn't it correct to assume, the methods from ADODB should be used rather than using the direct Mysqli queries. 
@user3132858 : To answer your query "do I also need to change all instances of MySQL_* functions to MySQLi_* or ADODB takes care of this automatically"
The answer is YES, ADO takes care of it automatically. it switches and includes the required driver as passed while connecting.

Answer (score 3):

1) I would suggest you to use pdo_mysql instead of mysql since it has better support for transactions.

2) ADODB initializes the driver being used (e.g. mysql or pdo_mysql) by using the dsn identifier from the connection string i.e. pdo_mysql://localhost/mydb or mysql://localhost/mydb.

Just switch mysql -> pdo_mysql in the connection string and it starts to use mysqli -driver instead.

3) Driver loading logic is located on row ~4860 at adodb.inc.php, and at least in the version I'm using from composer, there is no switch to be able to configure mysqli, but it upgrades mysql -> mysqli automatically if you have PHP 7.0.0 or higher. You could tweak this code to force mysqli also by adding one if-statement, but then you have a custom fork of ADODB. Maybe do a pull request.

```
        case 'mysql':
            // mysql driver deprecated since 5.5, removed in 7.0
            // automatically switch to mysqli
            if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0', '>=')) {
                $db = 'mysqli';
            }
            $class = $db;
            break;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the very solution that helps me update the code cleanly. The up-to-date adodb-5.20.15 only added support for more db's, not upgrade mysql to mysqli. Your patch does the trick. I'm now working on other problems resulted from features removed by PHP7.0.

Comment: Apt, and should be the accepted answer. A way cleaner way to solve the stated problem.